ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pil (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pil
1#"Ive tried to install onto pycharm and im gettin"
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement upgrade (from versions: none)
(https://i.sstatic.net/jThSN.png)
#tried to download pillow like ive seen recommended alot. when i run that through pycharm im fine still getting error in my #import

Requirement already satisfied usually means the package is already installed in your computer.
So you already have pillow installed!
You can run pip list to verify that Pillow is installed in your computer. You can also run pip show pillow to see details about pillow

yea it says its there. but same problem occurs. my import           #import PIL.Image, pil.ImageTk   is still throwing a package not installed promt.

Do you need import PIL.Image? Or do you actually need from PIL import Image? https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

i m dumb ! i found the issue. Thank you

So what's the issue?

my issuse was i had. #  pil.ImageTk when it should have been PIL.ImageTk.
